# python strftime apply timezone or add 3 hours

Tags: python

I want to apply timezone for meeting_time.strftime

```
def format_filename(recording, file_type, recording_type):
    uuid = recording['uuid']
    topic = recording['topic'].replace('/', ' ').replace(':', '').replace('?', '')
    rec_type = recording_type.replace("_", " ").title()
    meeting_time = parse(recording['start_time'])
    return '{} - {} UTC - {}.{}'.format(
        meeting_time.strftime('%Y.%m.%d'), meeting_time.strftime('%H.%M %p'), topic+" - "+rec_type, file_type.lower())
```

Example of filename I got with code above- 2020.12.02 - 10.00

Filename I want - 2020.12.02 - 13.00

Original code - https://github.com/ricardorodrigues-ca/zoom-recording-downloader

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) and [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects).

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
print((datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=3)).strftime('%Y.%m.%d - %H.%M'))
```

**Output**

```
2020.12.02 - 14.39
```

This will print the time after 3 hours from now.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

d = '2020.12.02 - 10.00'
result = datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(d, '%Y.%m.%d - %H.%M') + timedelta(hours=3), '%Y.%m.%d - %H.%M')
```

The result will be:

```
'2020.12.02 - 13.00'
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is add 3 hours, you can do it as:

```py
new_datetime = datetime.datetime.today() + datetime.timedelta(hours=3)
```

This adds 3 hours to your previous datetime.

If you want to make use of timezone's, you can find about it in Python's official documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.tzinfo

Answer (score 0):

Let us make time conversion in a standard and robust way:

In order to covert time between zones:

1- Spcify the zone in which DateTime was recorded.

2- Convert the scpecified DateTime to the required time zone.

The mentioned steps are explained in the followin example:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

# Choose any datetime
datetime_local=datetime(2020,12,2,10,00)
print(datetime_local)

# specifiy/include the time zone in the datetime for example ('Brazil/East') (-3.00)
datetime_brazil = timezone('Brazil/East').localize(datetime_local)
print('Brazil')
print(datetime_brazil)

# Convert it to UTC time zone
datetime_utc = datetime_brazil.astimezone(timezone('Etc/Universal'))
print('UTC')
print(datetime_utc)

# Convert the time to Cairo time zone
datetime_cairo = datetime_brazil.astimezone(timezone('Africa/Cairo'))
print('Cairo')
print(datetime_cairo)
```

The output

```
2020-12-02 10:00:00
Brazil
2020-12-02 10:00:00-03:00
UTC
2020-12-02 13:00:00+00:00
Cairo
2020-12-02 15:00:00+02:00
```

We Can get the list of time zone by the followin code:

```
import pytz
for tz in pytz.all_timezones:
    print(tz)
```

the output list:

```
Africa/Abidjan
Africa/Accra
Africa/Addis_Ababa
Africa/Algiers
...
...
```

Applying the steps mentioned above to the code in the question,

if the recorded DateTime was in Brazil and we want to convert it to UTC so we modify the code as follows:

```
def format_filename(recording, file_type, recording_type):
    uuid = recording['uuid']
    topic = recording['topic'].replace('/', ' ').replace(':', '').replace('?', '')
    rec_type = recording_type.replace("_", " ").title()
    meeting_time = parse(recording['start_time'])
    
    # Start of modification 
    # Sepcify the local time zone, (localize it)
    meeting_timt_local = timezone('Brazil/East').localize(meeting_time) 
    # Convert specified/localized DateTime to utc
    meeting_time_utc = meeting_timt_local.astimezone(timezone('Etc/Universal'))
    # return the formated meeting_time in utc
    return '{} - {} UTC - {}.{}'.format(
        meeting_time_utc.strftime('%Y.%m.%d'), meeting_time_utc.strftime('%H.%M %p'), topic+" - "+rec_type, file_type.lower())
```

Goog Luck